# How to stop getchar() from receiving extra ENTER?

Tags: c

I have received an assignment which asked me to make a function to get a string using getchar() to do things in a do/while loop with the ending condition is when while dectected ENTER. However, it keep shutting down because getchar() keep getting the ENTER after inputting a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    /* Variables Declare Here */

    int vowel = 0;
    int consonant = 0;
    int other = 0;
    int decimal;

    /* Main Function Here */

    do
    {
        printf("Enter a character:\n");
        decimal = toupper(getchar());
        if (decimal >= 65 && decimal <= 90)
            {
                if (decimal == 65 or decimal == 69 or decimal == 73 or decimal == 79 or decimal == 85)
                    vowel ++;
                else
                    consonant ++;
            }
        else
            other ++;
        printf (" Vowel: %d\n Consonant: %d\n Other: %d\n", vowel, consonant, other);
    } while (decimal != EOF);

    /* End Function Here */
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

And this is what I got from my teacher:

```
Begin
    Do {
 Accept ch;   /* ch= getchar(); */
Convert ch to its uppercase /* ch= toupper(ch); */
If ( ch>=’A’ and ch <=’Z’) {
     switch (ch) {
         case ‘A’ :
         case ‘E’ :
         case ‘I’ :
         case ‘O’ :
         case ‘U’ : nVowels ++; break;
         default:  nConsonants++;
     }
}
else nOthers = nOthers++;
    }
    While ( ch != ‘\n’);
    Print out nVowels;
    Print out nConsonants;
    Print out nOthers;
End
```

Comment: You need to define `ch` as `int`. Both `getchar()` and `toupper()` work with ints.

Comment: After the printf displaced the character it immediately loop again with ENTER and shutdown the whole thing.

Comment: [Your program works as expected on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/96be5q)

Comment: Ah! you mean "shutting down" as "terminated". You want to [end the loop when `EOF` is signalled](https://ideone.com/Apjdyr). **Now, the `int ch;` thing is** very **important**.

Comment: It's working now with the EOF but still recording the ENTER in the function. Is there anyway to fix this or do I have to use another IF to subtract it out manually?

Comment: yep, you need to deal with `'\n'` manually.

Comment: **MUST BE `int ch;`** :)

Comment: Sorry if I was bad with my words. But my assignment is to make a Do/While loop as above. Could you please check again.

Comment: It looks OK. Just one thing: when `EOF` is signalled you treat that signal as a "other" character. **`EOF` is not a character, `EOF` is a signal.** You may want to end the loop right after you detect the signal and not update the count for "other" ... `if (decimal == EOF) break;`

Comment: It is considered bad practice to use "magic numbers" in the code. Why do you use numbers in your conditions while your teacher even provided proper representation as characters?